# Chrome Dev Tools: Divergence/error between flame chart and memory graph in "Timeline" profiling

Tags: profiling, google-chrome-devtools

While trying to debug long running, memory leaking code I observed a discrepancy between the memory graph and the flame chart. I suspected that this is a "natural" reading error.

I was trying to reproduce this behaviour with very simplified code and were successful...

[image: Chome dev tools showing the "Timeline" profiler - zoomed out]

The above chart was recorded while profiling this code:

```
    window.onload = function() {

        var count = 0;

        function addDelayed() {
            count++;

            if (count > 50) {
                return;
            }

            var x = document.createElement("div");
            x.addEventListener("click", function() {

            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                addDelayed();
            }, 1000);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            addDelayed();
        }, 10000);

    };
```

I've zoomed in to an arbitrary `listener` increase to know when it has occured:

[image: Chome dev tools showing the "Timeline" profiler - zoomed in]

I expected the `node` and `listener` raise to be at about the half of `Function call`, not behind it.

Can I assume that this is a measuring error or am I forgetting to take something else into account?

This was recorded with Chrome 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit) (but the behaviour can be observed with older versions too)

Answer (score 1):

Timeline captures number of event listeners/dom nodes right after timer fire event has finished. We do so for many other events so the step will be at the end of the corresponding event. Showing it somewhere in the middle of the event would be unfair and imprecise as we don't know exact moment when the number changed. On the other hand, tracking each individual node/listener creation/deletion would result in a much heavier instrumentation overhead which we want to avoid.